# selecting phone from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to send the messages to customers who has birthday today.
if 2 customers have birthday but it is sending SMS twice to first customer only.

my controller is like

```
$sms_count = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_customers where date_of_birth='". $today."' and concat('',phone * 1) = phone")->result();
$sender = $this->input->post($this->security->xss_clean('outlet_name'));
$message = $this->input->post($this->security->xss_clean('message'));
$numbers = array($this->db->query("select phone from tbl_customers where date_of_birth='". $today."'")->row('phone')); 

 foreach ($sms_count as $value) {  
                    try {
                        $result = $textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender); 
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('exception', 'SMS has been sent successfully!');
                    } 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get all data, then loop through that data and send SMS as below

```
 $this->db->select('phone');
 $this->db->where('date_of_birth', $today);
 $numbers = $this->db->get('tbl_customers')->result_array();
 if($numbers){
     foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
                $result = $textlocal->sendSms($value['phone'], $message, $sender); 
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('exception', 'SMS has been sent successfully!');

       }
   }
```

Comment: Getting following error Message: Undefined index: number. so i removed ['number'] from it. it worked fine with multiple number but giving error with single number.

Comment: Message: No valid numbers specified

Comment: i have updated the code , use `$value['phone']` instead of `$value['number']`

Comment: new error 'Message: Invalid $numbers format. Must be an array'

Comment: thats all very basic thing, just debug `$numbers`  and check what you get.

Comment: it worked after removing ['phone'] from $value['phone]. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your initial code you used row(), which meant you were only getting one number, rather than an array of numbers. Using result_array() gives you an associative array.

```
 $numbers = $this->db->select('phone')->get_where('date_of_birth', $today)->result_array();
 if(!empty($numbers)){
     foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
                 $result = $textlocal->sendSms($value['phone'], $message, $sender); 
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('exception', 'SMS has been sent successfully!');

       }
   } else {
                 var_dump($numbers);
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('exception', 'No Numbers found.');
}
```

This should be enough to help you debug your code if the SMS isn't sending.

As you are using a foreach loop regardless if the data is 1 or more it should still work.
If you are running this code within your application you will need to apply time logic and save the result of the SMS sending into your DB. So that it won't send again to the person by accident, If you are running this as a cron job then you have no problem providing its set to once a day.